# SQL SERVER: How to get the stored procedure text EXCLUDING comments?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, transaction, parse, comments

I need to find all the stored procs that use Transactions, as I want to enable transaction abort to those procedures.  However, --I didn't do this; it's inherited-- many of  the stored procedures contain testing procedures with in comment blocks and most of the tests contain transaction blocks. I am only interested in changing stored procs that actually use transactions. AND I want to be able to monitor when stored procs are updated so that I can make sure that this flag is set.

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
```

Addendum: based on comments, here're some examples from my system.

```
/*
-- clean up after tests
BEGIN TRANSACTION
EXEC dbo.AR_Cleanup_MoveEqualAndOppositeSBPLiabilities
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
*/

/*
Use case: 147
BEGIN TRANSACTION
....
*/
```

Comment: `. I am only interested in changing stored procs that actually use transactions`  - are you looking for an explicit `begin tran .. end tran` ?

Comment: Yes, I'm currently only looking for:  %BEGIN TRANSACTION%

Comment: I think that writing your own parser that eliminates comments would be a lot harder than just manually investigating to see false positives. YMMV.

Comment: I'm hoping that there is a parser or SP_ proc that will strip out the comments. I agree with Aaron that I do not want to write my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that I put together that worked, at least in my testing.

It relies on dbo.DelimitedSplit8K by Jeff Moden which you can find here https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%e2%80%9ccsv-splitter%e2%80%9d-function

You just need to change it to use sys.sql_modules to sub in for the procname and proccode portions.

```
DECLARE @Sample AS TABLE
    (
    procname NVARCHAR(128) NOT NULL
    , proccode NVARCHAR(512) NOT NULL
    )

INSERT INTO @Sample
(procname, proccode)
VALUES ('test1-false'
    , N'/*
-- clean up after tests
BEGIN TRANSACTION
EXEC dbo.AR_Cleanup_MoveEqualAndOppositeSBPLiabilities
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
*/
Do Stuff
')
, ('test2-true'
    , N'
BEGIN TRANSACTION
EXEC dbo.AR_Cleanup_MoveEqualAndOppositeSBPLiabilities
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
')
, ('test3-both'
    , N'
/*
-- clean up after tests
BEGIN TRANSACTION
EXEC dbo.AR_Cleanup_MoveEqualAndOppositeSBPLiabilities
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
*/
BEGIN TRANSACTION
EXEC dbo.AR_Cleanup_MoveEqualAndOppositeSBPLiabilities
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
')

DECLARE @Split NCHAR(1) = N'
'

/** NOTE: Using dbo.DelimitedSplit8K by Jeff Moden
    from https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%e2%80%9ccsv-splitter%e2%80%9d-function
    */

;WITH CTE_Split AS
    (
    SELECT S.procname
        , T.ItemNumber AS LineNumber
        , T.Item AS Line
        , LineType = CASE   WHEN T.Item LIKE '%/*%' THEN 'CommentStart'
                            WHEN T.Item LIKE '%*/%' THEN 'CommentEnd'
                            WHEN T.Item LIKE '%--%BEGIN TRAN%' THEN 'Commented'
                            WHEN T.Item LIKE '%--%ROLLBACK%' THEN 'Commented'
                            WHEN T.Item LIKE '%--%COMMIT%' THEN 'Commented'
                            WHEN T.Item LIKE '%BEGIN TRAN%' AND NOT(T.Item LIKE '%--%BEGIN TRAN%') THEN 'TransactionStart'
                            WHEN T.Item LIKE '%ROLLBACK%' AND NOT(T.Item LIKE '%--%ROLLBACK%') THEN 'TransactionRollback'
                            WHEN T.Item LIKE '%COMMIT%' AND NOT(T.Item LIKE '%--%COMMIT%') THEN 'TransactiionCommit'
                            ELSE ''
                            END
    FROM @Sample AS S 
        CROSS APPLY [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K](proccode, @Split) AS T
    )
, CTE_CommentBlocks AS
    (
    SELECT procname, CommentStart, CommentEnd
    FROM (SELECT procname, LineType, LineNumber FROM CTE_Split WHERE LineType IN ('CommentStart', 'CommentEnd')) AS S
        PIVOT (MIN(LineNumber) FOR LineType IN (CommentStart, CommentEnd)) AS P
    )
, CTE_Commented AS
    (
    SELECT S.*
        , CommentedOut = CASE WHEN B.procname IS NOT NULL THEN 'Y' ELSE 'TRANSACTION' END
    FROM CTE_Split AS S
        LEFT OUTER JOIN CTE_CommentBlocks AS B ON B.procname = S.procname AND S.LineNumber BETWEEN B.CommentStart AND B.CommentEnd
    WHERE LineType <> ''
    )
SELECT * FROM CTE_Commented
```

Comment: Thank you, just what I needed.

Comment: False positive though if something that *looks* like a comment is just inside a string or an entity, e.g. `SELECT [/* Not a comment */] = 'This is /* not a comment */' FROM sys.objects AS [/* also not a comment */];`

Comment: True, it is imperfect, and I should have done a better job detailing all the ways it could break.  But given the specific use case of searching for begin transactions that aren’t commented out, I think it’s probably good enough for purpose.

Comment: Yep was just adding a disclaimer for the OP. Parsing is by definition imperfect.

Answer (score 4):

Below is a PowerShell example that uses the [Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.transactsql.scriptdom) to parse procs and identify those with `BEGIN TRAN` statements. This version will download the assembly from NuGet if `Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.dll` doesn't already exist in the specified location. You could use a package manager instead for that task.

```
param (
    # Location of Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.dll assembly.
    $scriptDomAssemblyPath = "C:\Temp\Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.dll",
    # Url of Microsoft.SqlServer.DacFx.x64 in official Microsoft NuGet repository.
    $scriptDomNuGetUrl = "https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/Microsoft.SqlServer.DacFx.x64/150.4200.1"
)

$procQuery = @"
SELECT
      QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(p.object_id)) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(p.name) AS ProcedureName
    , m.definition
FROM sys.procedures AS p
JOIN sys.sql_modules AS m ON m.object_id = p.object_id;
"@

# Add Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom assembly, downloading if needed
Function Add-ScriptDomAssemblyType ($scriptDomAssemblyPath, $scriptDomNuGetUrl) {

    # if T-SQL script DOM assembly does not exist, download from NuGet and extract assembly from package to $scriptDomAssemblyPath
    if(![System.IO.File]::Exists($scriptDomAssemblyPath)) {
        if([String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($scriptDomNuGetUrl)) {
            throw "Script DOM assembly not found at $scriptDomAssemblyPath and NuGet package download Url not specified"
        }
        $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $scriptDomNuGetUrl
        if ($response.StatusCode -ne 200) {
            throw "Unable to download Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom NuGet package: $response.StatusCode : $response.StatusDescription"
        }
        $tempZipFilePath = [System.IO.Path]::Combine([System.IO.Path]::GetTempPath(), [System.IO.Path]::GetRandomFileName() + ".zip")
        [System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($tempZipFilePath, $response.Content)
        $response.BaseResponse.Dispose()
        $tempUnzipFolderPath = [System.IO.Path]::Combine([System.IO.Path]::GetTempPath(), [System.IO.Path]::GetRandomFileName())
        Expand-Archive -Path $tempZipFilePath -DestinationPath $tempUnzipFolderPath
        $tempZipFilePath | Remove-Item
        Move-Item "$tempUnzipFolderPath\lib\net46\Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.dll" "C:\Temp\Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.dll"
        $tempUnzipFolderPath | Remove-Item -Recurse
    }

    # load assembly into app domain so it can be used in this script
    Add-Type -Path $scriptDomAssemblyPath
}

# parse CREATE PROCEDURE script, returning true if it contains a BEGIN TRAN T-SQL statement
Function Test-HasBeginTrasaction ($procText) {

    # use TSql parser appropriate for targetted SQL Server version
    $parser = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.TSql140Parser($true)
    $parseErrors = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.ParseError]
    $scriptReader = New-Object System.IO.StringReader($procText)
    $fragment = $parser.Parse($scriptReader, [ref]$parseErrors)
    if($parseErrors.Count -gt 0)
    {
        # parsing errors may occur for existing stored procs if the code is invalid due to obsolete T-SQL syntax
        throw "$($parseErrors.Count) parsing errors: $( ( $parseErrors | ConvertTo-Json ) )"
    }

    # evaluate each statement in stored procedure
    foreach ($statement in $fragment.Batches[0].Statements[0].StatementList.Statements) {
        # return true if a BeginTransactionStatement is found
        if ($statement.GetType().Name -eq "BeginTransactionStatement") {
            return $true
        }
    }

    # return false if no BeginTransactionStatement is found
    return $false

}

############
### main ###
############

try {

    Add-ScriptDomAssemblyType -scriptDomAssemblyPath $scriptDomAssemblyPath -scriptDomNuGetUrl $scriptDomNuGetUrl

    $connectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=YourDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI"
    $connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($connectionString)
    $command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($procQuery, $connection)
    $connection.Open()
    $reader = $command.ExecuteReader()
    while($reader.Read()) {

        $hasBeginTransaction = Test-HasBeginTrasaction -procText $reader["definition"]

        if( $hasBeginTransaction ) {
            Write-Host "Has BEGIN TRANSACTION: $($reader["ProcedureName"])"
        }

    }
    $reader.Close()
    $connection.Close()

}
catch {
    throw
}
```

This can be easily extended to also check for `SET XACT_ABORT ON` in order to include only those procs that need attention, assuming `SET XACT_ABORT ON` is properly placed in the proc code. Below is an additional function and body code to do this.

```
# parse CREATE PROCEDURE script, returning true if it contains a SET XACT_ABORT ON
Function Test-HasSetXactAbortOn ($procText) {

    # use TSql parser appropriate for targetted SQL Server version
    $parser = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.TSql140Parser($true)
    $parseErrors = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.ParseError]
    $scriptReader = New-Object System.IO.StringReader($procText)
    $fragment = $parser.Parse($scriptReader, [ref]$parseErrors)
    if($parseErrors.Count -gt 0)
    {
        # parsing errors may occur for existing stored procs if the code is invalid due to obsolete T-SQL syntax
        throw "$($parseErrors.Count) parsing errors: $( ( $parseErrors | ConvertTo-Json ) )"
    }

    # evaluate each statement in stored procedure
    foreach ($statement in $fragment.Batches[0].Statements[0].StatementList.Statements) {
        # return true if a SET XACT_ABORT ON is found
        if (($statement.GetType().Name -eq "PredicateSetStatement") -and
            ($statement.Options -band [Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.SetOptions]::XactAbort) -and
            $statement.IsOn ) {
            return $true
        }
    }

    # return false if no SET XACT_ABORT ON is found
    return $false

}

############
### main ###
############

try {

    Add-ScriptDomAssemblyType -scriptDomAssemblyPath $scriptDomAssemblyPath -scriptDomNuGetUrl $scriptDomNuGetUrl

    $connectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=YourDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI"
    $connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($connectionString)
    $command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($procQuery, $connection)
    $connection.Open()
    $reader = $command.ExecuteReader()
    while($reader.Read()) {

        $hasBeginTransaction = Test-HasBeginTrasaction -procText $reader["definition"]
        $hasSetXactAbortOn = Test-HasSetXactAbortOn -procText $reader["definition"]

        if( $hasBeginTransaction -and !$hasSetXactAbortOn ) {
            Write-Host "Has BEGIN TRANSACTION without SET_XACT_ABORT ON: $($reader["ProcedureName"])"
        }

    }
    $reader.Close()
    $connection.Close()

}
catch {
    throw
}
```

Comment: This would be great but for the fact that I need a sql based solution. I'm sure others will be able to use it though.

Comment: @Displayname Given that using a DOM is much more reliable than parsing text, can you explain why the only possible solution can be in T-SQL?